# Buck converter - what to do with the rest of the duty cycle

Tags: buck, solar-charge-controller

I am looking into making a MPPT charge controller for some solar panels - I understand that it works on the basis of using buck converters to get the most efficient voltage to current ratio for the battery. However in using the buck converter is there anything that can be done with the solar panels for the parts when the duty cycle isn't active. It seems the formula for output voltage is just the duty cycle times the input voltage - so if I had 20 V from the panels and it needed to be at 12 V then the duty cycle would be 60%, but what about the 40% of the time when the panels are not connected to anything? Is that extra power just doomed to not be used?

Would it be possible to make a secondary buck converter that took up all the cycles the primary one wasn't using (e.g. the 40%) and then get it to match the voltage to the first one dynamically? And if so how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Nothing is wasted, the input capacitor is refilled by your panels during switching off-period. Also, voltage to current ratio is what you need in your PV panel side to get to maximum power point but your battery does not have such a rule. You will charge it with as much current the MPPT can track and a set voltage limit.

Comment: Your concept of MPPT is a little backward. The point is to vary the load (charging) current so that maximum power from the panels is maintained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a buck MPPT converter it is a requirement that there is a input capacitor at the power input of the converter.

During the portion of the cycle when the switch is not taking power from the source the energy from the source charges the capacitor for use during the on time. No energy is wasted.

The capacitor needs to be large enough so the ripple is small relative to the input voltage.